# Null Foreign Key in Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a classic scenario Product-Brand relation. And my classes like this.

```
    public class Products
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string PreDescription { get; set; }

        public int? BrandID { get; set; }

        //private Brands brand;
        public virtual Brands Brand
        {
            get; //{ if (this.Brand == null) Brand = new Brands(); return Brand; }
            set; //{ Brand = value; }
        }
    } 

    public class Brands
    {
        public int BrandID { get; set; }
        public string BrandName { get; set; }

        private List products;
        public virtual List Products
        {
            get{ if (this.products == null) products = new List(); return products; }
            set{ products = value; }
        }
    }
```

And mapping like this.

```
    public class ProductsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration{
        public ProductsMap()
        {
            ToTable("Products");
            HasKey(p => p.ProductID).Property(p => p.ProductID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            this.HasOptional(p => p.Brand).WithMany(b => b.Products);
        }
    }

    public class BrandsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration
    {
        public BrandsMap()
        {
            ToTable("Brands");
            HasKey(b => b.BrandID).Property(b => b.BrandID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);         
        }
    }
```

I have two method, GetAll(), GetByID()
Some row on the Product table has Null value.

When Im try to run GetAll method it throwing Null Exception (Some Product's brand return null), But all product getting by GetByID() dosent throwing any exception?

Comment: What does `GetAll()` look like...

Answer (score 0):

While Getting values from dB include the associated table(Products) along with parent table(Brands).

Example:

```
var brands=context.Brand.include("Products");
```

Comment: Still im getting this error on GetAll() method. if there is null value as well as int value in the returned data, it throw exception.

Comment: I think the `BrandID` should not be optional. Change it to `public int BrandID { get; set; }`.